# Xorg freezes temporarily when playing video games

Tags: xorg, gaming

I have a  laptop with a GTX 3060 running manjaro i3 on Xorg. with  x86_64 Linux 6.1.25-1-MANJARO. Whenever I try to play a game, eventually, Xorg temporarily freezes for 1-3 seconds. Sometimes it even freezes permanently until I kill the game by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-F2 to open a console. Neither Xorg nor dmesh indicate anything unusual. How do I diagnose this problem?